# Generating an array of records from an Activerecord::Relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relation

Fairly new to Rails, building an e-commerce system.

I have a tree-like structure of products -> skus -> line_items

where:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sku
  belongs_to :cart

class Sku < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skus
  has_many :line_items, :through => :skus
```

The Product model has a boolean field that determines whether or not a specific product requires a license.

Multiple line_items are added to a cart, so that:

```
@cart.line_items
```

returns an array of line items.

At the order stage, I need to determine whether or not any of the line items need a license, and if so, display the license for acceptance.

I have tried linking scopes:

```
 class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :license?, joins(:sku) & Sku.license?

class Sku < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :license?, joins(:product) & Product.license?

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :license?, where(:license => true)



@cart.line_items.license?
```

results in an empty array, even when @cart.line_items contains items that have product.license as true.

I've tried:

```
@cart.line_items.joins(:sku).joins(:product).where(:license => true)
```

which returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, but

```
@cart.line_items.joins(:sku).joins(:product).where(:rct => true).empty?
@cart.line_items.joins(:sku).joins(:product).where(:rct => true).to_a
@cart.line_items.joins(:sku).joins(:product).where(:rct => true).all
```

all fail to give either a boolean (in the first case) or an array in the second two cases.

I can loop through:

```
<% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
    <h4><%= item %></h4>
    <h4><%= item.sku.product.license %></h4>
<% end %>
```

and see all the correct booleans, but there has to be a better way to do this than either using a variation of this loop in my order view, or having to create a class method to loop through and generate the boolean.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the Product is the one that understands whether it needs a licence or not. In which case, you need to go up the chain from the line_item all the way to the product to fetch that info. You could add a `needs_license?` method on the `LineItem` class which delegates to its Sku, which delegates to its product, and then filter out LineItems like so:

```
class LineItem
  def needs_license?
    sku.needs_license?
  end
end
class Sku
  def needs_license?
    product.needs_license?
  end
end

class Product
  def needs_license?
    license
  end
end
```

Finally,

```
@cart.line_items.select(&:needs_license?)
```

Comment: Thanks much! That works perfectly, and is what I thought I was doing with the linked scopes. The linked class methods are obviously doing something different.